# Login into a phone with broken screen using adb

Tags: adb, backup, lock-screens, broken-screen

I have a Android 10 phone with broken screen (it doesn't display anything and doesn't react to touches) that has ADB enabled. It boots (probably to the lockscreen) as I can see it in `adb devices` and it gets an IP, but unfortunately `adb devices` lists it as unauthorized.

I tried unlocking it with a keyboard via USB-OTG (pressing the power button, then pressing enter (not sure if needed), then waiting a moment (in case enter only caused a wrong pin message) and then entering the PIN again and pressing enter, but it doesn't seem to change things and I cannot see if it was successful.
My PC is authorized and usually I was able to use adb pull/shell/..., but I think this might have required unlocking the screen.

Is there a way to get somehow blindly authorize adb access to the data?

Comment: Your main problem is that adb requires the phone to operate as USB client where as connecting an USB keyboard/mouse requires the phone to operate in OTG mode as USB hosts. To my knowledge both modes can not be used at the same time and the adb authorization dialog vanishes once you disconnect the adb usb connection. So the only way would be to use the USB keyboard to pair a bluetooth keyboard, then switch to adb ,mode and use the bluetooth keyboard to authorize adb. Doing that all blind is next to impossible.

Comment: Good point. The question is whether the popup always appears after a reboot, even for known devices. I know it does not appear for every new connection, but it may reappear after a reboot. I hoped that unlocking with OTG first and then connecting to a computer would result in an authorized adb connection (since the computer previously was authorized), but it is still unauthorized and I can't see if there is a popup or not.

Comment: Adb authorization Dialog only appears upon first connection (or better every time the connection is established until you agree go it) . But since Android 12 or 13 there is a function active by default that removes the trust state after some weeks or months. This function can be disabled in developer settings.

Comment: It's Android 10 and seems to still have adb but unauthorized. Sadly I have no idea what's on the screen and the phone also does not support HDMI output. Usually I use adb all the time, so I am also confused why it is not authorized.